# Connect To Virtual Terminals Remotely - Steamlink

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

**UPDATE:**
I got this to sort of work via SSH from PuTTY on my pc, and then running `sudo chvt 4` and then `steamlink >/dev/tty4`. Only caveat here is that there's no graphical feedback , and basically renders RealVNC + VNC viewer useless (i.e. if I were to leave the pi on a tty accidentally and then try to access the pi via VNC outside of my home network I'm essentially screwed unless I open the ports for ssh which I'd rather not do for security reasons).

So if anyone has a solution to that aspect of this problem that would be great!

---

Ok so this is a bit of an odd scenario...

I have a raspberry pi running Bullseye, and I'm trying to get SteamLink to work with it. Running it from my pi's desktop gives me the error:

"X11 is not supported on this version of Raspbian. You can run on the console or downgrade to Raspberry Pi Buster."

Switching to a virtual terminal via `chvt N` or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and then running `steamlink` there works perfectly fine, but with the tv being upstairs and my pc downstairs, I'd rather be able to just remotely get it set up without having to bring a mouse / keyboard all the way upstairs...

Using RealVNC apparently doesn't output the non-GUI terminals so that isn't an option. I've tried using `openvt` to start it up in a virtual terminal as well but that requires sudo to run, and on doing that I get the error "Cannot run as root user," which is apparently an unavoidable Steam thing...

So basically is there any way at all to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? In a perfect world I'd like to be able to see the app running visually (either via VNC or something similar to X11 forwarding via ssh) so I know it's working without having to run up and down the stairs, and I'd rather not downgrade to Buster.

Here's a link to an article regarding SteamLink on the pi as a reference:
https://blog.iancolwell.ca/steamlink-aarch64

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What type of program is `steamlink`. What I understood is when you start it in a graphical desktop environment it wants to use X11 which is not available. When you start it in a virtual console, does it display a graphical user interface? Is there a text-only alternative? Show the exact `openvt` command that results in the error message `Cannot run as root user`. What error message do you get when you run it without `sudo`? There might be a different way to solve permissions problems.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but, at least for the basic use (I just use it to start GUI apps remotely, with the Pi attached to a screen) [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) is quick and simple, the server occupies ~100MB RSS.  However, it uses about 25% total CPU time on a Pi 4 when connected remotely and in use, which is not a big deal if you only need access occasionally for a few minutes.